# Accessing the json values on django template

Tags: python, json, django, facebook

I have finally got a way to access the various values from the facebook using `django-allauth`. The only issue that I am facing is in the accessing of the values on the template.

Here is the `views.py`:

```
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialToken

import json
import requests


def fb_personality_traits(request):
    access_token = SocialToken.objects.get(account__user=request.user, account__provider='facebook')
    # print access_token.token
    requested_data = requests.get(
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + access_token.token + '&fields=id,name,email,posts,about')
    data_FB = json.loads(requested_data)
    return render(request, 'home/facebook_personality_traits.html', {'fb': data_FB})
```

Here is the template taht I am using to display the values:

```
<html>


<body>

 Welcome back {{ user.name }}
 {{fb.name}}
<!-- <img src="" height="60" width="60"> -->


<a href="/">Home</a>



</body>


</html>
```

I am getting the following error:

Please let me know what to improve.

[image: FB - ERROR]

** Error in text **

```
TypeError at /facebook_personality_traits/
expected string or buffer
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://website:port/facebook_personality_traits/
Django Version: 1.11.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
expected string or buffer
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py in decode, line 364
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/home/ubuntu/PersonalityWithFacebook',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 11 Oct 2017 11:00:14 +0000
```

This is the json I am storing in the json variable:  [gist of the json](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/41e005d07beaa50a73c6901c3338990d)

Comment: *i.stack.imgur.com is currently unable to handle this request.* The more reason why errors should be added as part of the text, not as images.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Just a moment I am adding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requests.get()` returns a `response` object (the representation of a HTTP response), not a string, so obviously `json.loads()` crashes on it. What you want here is:

```
response = requests.get(...)
fb_data = json.loads(response.text)
```

Now `requests` is smart enough to have a `json()` method that will take care of the `json.loads()` part if the response has an 'application/json' content type, so you can just use it instead:

```
response = requests.get(...)
fb_data = response.json()
```

This being said, you should not blindly assume your request succeeded - you could have an error at the transport level (network / dns / etc), or you could have a 403, 404, 500 or whatever response, so you'll have to handle all the error cases around the `requests.get()` call.

As a last note: use string formatting instead of strings concatenation - it makes the code much more readable and maintainable:

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={token}&fields=id,name,email,posts,about'.format(token=access_token.token)
```

FWIW you can [pass the query part as a dict](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) too (and it's actually the best practice):

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me'
params = {
    "access_token": access_token.token, 
    "fields": "id,name,email,posts,about"
    }
response = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

Answer (score 1):

requested_data = requests.get('some_url') returns only response value

Ex:

Ref Image:  [Response display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rllmu.png)

So if you are using requests.get, then you have to use some function to get the data from the response.

Like requested_data.content which results in JSON data and you can send this to template and use.

I have used below sample code to test

```
import requests
import json

requested_data = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={my_fb_id_token}&fields=id,name,email')
print("Requested Data Content= %s"%requested_data.content)
print("Requested Data = %s"%requested_data)
```

And able to get the data like below

```
Requested Data Content= b'{"id":"1234569789011121","name":"Soma Naresh","email":"xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"}'
Requested Data = <Response [200]>
```

Let me know if I am wrong.